# i want all images selected one by one with a click on image from html, how do i loop over them in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a memory game and want to loop through all images one by one in javascript.
The idea is to put it in the ImageUrl variable i have made connected to the newCard variable and loop over every image one by one by click on html image.

I've tried to research it but can't find any answers.

This is what i have for code:

```js
function populateField() {
    for (let i = 0; i < myCardSet.length; i++) {
        let newTile = document.createElement('div');
        let newCard = document.createElement('img');
        let imageURL = document.getElementById('field').getElementsByTagName('img')
    for (let i of imageURL) {
        let ImageSrc = i.getAttribute('name')
        console.log(ImageSrc.substring(ImageSrc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
    }
        newCard.setAttribute('src', imageURL)
        newCard.setAttribute('name', imageURL)
        newTile.appendChild(newCard)
        myField.appendChild(newTile)
        let img = {
            src: 'cover.png',
            class: '.covered'
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="field"><img src="../begin/img/calf.jpg" alt="" name="calf">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
    </div>

    <script src="js/memory.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Please help,
Thanks already!